# Dependency update in Gradle results in a number of challenging errors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

In Build.gradle(Module :app), I updated the following,

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

to this,

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

and began getting the following errors reported,

[image]

Any suggestions as to where to look for the problem? I have tried swapping individual dependencies to narrow the problem down, but updating any of the first five will cause the error. Just updated to Gradle 8.0.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
//implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
//implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```